# RecordNumber vertically in Crystall report with two Column

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with 2 column, I was try Format Using Multiple Column and in layout I am checked Accross then Down, because I want to display a record balance for each column:

```
+----+------------+----+------------+
|No. | Data       |No. | Data       |
+----+------------+----+------------+
|1   | Data1      |2   | Data2      |
|3   | Data1      |4   | Data2      |
|5   | Data1      |6   | Data2      |
+----+------------+----+------------+
```

or

```
+----+------------+----+------------+
|No. | Data       |No. | Data       |
+----+------------+----+------------+
|1   | Data1      |2   | Data2      |
|3   | Data1      |    |            |
+----+------------+----+------------+
```

But I want to show record number continuous vertically just like this:

```
+----+------------+----+------------+
|No. | Data       |No. | Data       |
+----+------------+----+------------+
|1   | Data1      |4   | Data2      |
|2   | Data1      |5   | Data2      |
|3   | Data1      |6   | Data2      |
+----+------------+----+------------+
```

I was try to create a formula, but the results were not as I wanted. Can you help me to solve my problem?

Comment: where are you placing those 2 columns in report?

Comment: @Siva At detail section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer, here formula:

```
NumberVar nMidData := RoundUp(count({Table.data})/2);
NumberVar nRecord := count({Table.data});

WhilePrintingRecords;
if ((RecordNumber>=1) and (RecordNumber mod 2)=1) then
(
    NumberVar RecNoLeft:=RecNoLeft+1;
)
else if ((Recordnumber>=2) and (RecordNumber mod 2)=0) then
(
    NumberVar RecNoRight:=RecNoRight+1;
    nMidData+RecNoRight;
)
```

I put this formula in detail column `No`.

Answer (score 1):

ok follow below approach:

1. Take two subreports and place in detail:

   ```
   first sub report for Data1 //limit the size of sub report to number of columns
   Second sub report for Data2 // place adjacent to sub report 1 and limit size
   ```
2. In sub report 1

Create a formula `@Reset` and place in `Report Header`

```
Shared NumberVar count;
count:=0;
```

Create one more formula `@Display` and place in details at `No` field of your question.

```
Shared Numbervar count;
Shared Numbervar store;
count:=count+1;
store:=count;
count;
```

Now you have numbered data for column1.

1. Go to second sub report for coulmn2 measn `Data2`. in your question

Create one more formula `@Display` and place in details at `No` field of your question.

```
Shared Numbervar store;
store:=store+1;
```

Now you have number your `data2`.

Let me know incase any issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry if I'm late response. But I've found the answer myself. Not using two sub-reports, because I was the difficulty in designing a sub report. So, I was using a formula.

Comment: No Problem... can you post the solution...Just was curious to know the approach.